# Sieve of Eratosthenes UNIX Script

Tags: bash, unix

I'm writing a UNIX script to use the sieve to generate prime numbers. I keep getting a bad modulo division on line 19, and I can't seem to figure out why.

I have tried all kinds of different formatting, not sure what the right way is.

```
#!bin/bash
read -p "Upper limit? :" answer
theMultiple=2

#populate the array
for ((i=2;i<$answer;i++)); do
   sieveArray[$i]=$i
done
#Use Sieve
for ((i=0;i<=${#sieveArray[*]}; i++)); do
   if [ $[$(($[${sieveArray[$i]}] % $theMultiple))] -eq 0 ]; then
         theMultiple=${sieveArray[$i]}
         echo $theMultiple
         for ((j=$i;j<${#sieveArray[*]};j++)); do
            if [ $[$(($[${sieveArray[$j]}] % $theMultiple))] -eq 0 ]; then
               sieveArray[$j]=0
            fi
         done
   fi
done
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You start filling in your sieveArray at index 2, yet in your main loop you start using it at index zero. The first two elements are probably set to zero by default which causes a division by zero.

Comment: That stopped the division by 0.

Comment: The logic in the for loop isnt working properly, i and j are off by one?

Answer (score 0):

You could write it differently with less bash arithmetic and more commands :

```
#!/bin/bash
limit=$1
sieve="$(seq 2 $limit|sort)"

for n in 2 $(seq 3 2 $limit)
do
  sieve="$(comm -23 <(echo "$sieve") <(seq $(($n * $n)) $n $limit|sort))"
done

echo "$sieve"|sort -n
```

`seq` is used to generate lists of numbers and multiples.
`comm` is used to remove the multiples from the `sieve` variable. As `comm` expects data sorted un alphabetical order (10 is before 9), the lists of number must be sorted every time.

The `for` loop is slightly optimized to not include even numbers, except 2.

Comment: Interesting solution.  I'm just beginning to program and script, never heard of those commands